# "Silicon Power 4GB Micro SDHC Class 10 High Speed Memory Card" compatible with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, compatibility, sd-card, raspberry-pi

Today I bought a "Silicon Power 4GB Micro SDHC Class 10 High Speed Memory Card". Is this compatible with Raspberry Pi Model B?

Comment: Is the Pi picky about these things? Maybe link to a specific card, because they may make more than one card with those specs.

Comment: pis tend to be picky, and usually what most people do is buy the stock transend card with it. http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards its not on the list, but there's a good chance it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be compatible with it.

Generally, 4 GB SD card or above is recommended. 2GB also works most of the time.

As per Card type, Prescribed card type are: 
SD & SDHC

Regarding "class 10", there might not be any problem, as it means its performance(speed) is larger (10Mb/s) than lower versions.
Hence it can perform everything which lower versions(class 2, 4, 6) could do.